# Query not well formed in Sqlalchemy for select

Tags: postgresql, python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to generate the following raw query using sqlalchemy core:

```
SELECT library.name, (SELECT ARRAY (select book.title 
                      from books 
                      where book.library_id = 1 and book.is_free = false) as book_lists) 
from library 
where id = 1;
```

So the query I generate in sqlalchemy is:

```
query = sa.select(
  [
    library.name,
    sa.func.array(
      sa.select(
        [books.title]
      ).where(
        sa.and_(
          books.c.library_id == library_no,
          books.c.is_free == False,
        )
      ).alias('book_list')
    )
  ]
).where(
   library.c.id == library_no,
)
```

But the queries aren't equivalent

#### TL; DR:

Here are the table that I have in my postgresql:

Table: **library**

```
--------------------------------
| id |    name     |    owner  |
--------------------------------
|  1 |     ABC     |     A     |
|  2 |     DEF     |     D     |
|  3 |     GHI     |     G     |
--------------------------------
```

Table: **books**

```
-----------------------------------------
| id |    title    |  library  | is_free |
-----------------------------------------
|  a |     xxx     |     1     |    t    |
|  b |     yyy     |     1     |    f    |
|  c |     zzz     |     2     |    t    |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, and welome to the forum! If your SQL works through a client (psql, pgadmin, SQuirreL SQL - whatever, and works, then your problem isn't with PostgreSQL but rather your programming tool - SQLAlchemy...  then this is a programming problem, not a database one - I suggest that you go to StackOverflow for this question.